# What die rolls are open-ended?

Tags: burning-wheel

In Burning Wheel Gold, so far as I can tell, the following tests have open-ended die rolls:

- Magic
- Perception
- Any skill-based test with the funky little squiggly S after it (which are generally magic-based skills like elfsongs)
- Any skill-based test where the player decides to spend a Fate point to open the die rolls

Am I missing anything? I didn't think I was before, but I only recently came across Perception as being open-ended, so what do I know?

Comment: Are you playing Burning Wheel Revised or Burning Wheel Gold? Perception is no longer open-ended in Gold.

Comment: Ah ha! That's why I didn't see this in the rule book. BWG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got most of them.

> *Burning Wheel Gold, page 16*
>
> Tests for Steel, Faith and any ability considered “magical” (Dwarven Arts, Elven Skill Songs or Sorcery, for example) are all open-ended rolls.

For example, Orc Hatred and skills rooted in Hatred are also open-ended due to their magical nature. You can spend Fate artha for Luck (page 66) to open-end a test that is not already open-ended.

Perception is not open-ended as of Burning Wheel Gold.